# Randomly sample from ActiveRecord collection object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Suppose we have something of class

```
@physician.availabilities.class
=> Availability::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

@physician.availabilities.length
=> 72
```

How can we randomly sample records from this object?

E.g. this looks promising

```
@physician.availabilities.sample(5)
```

execept that

```
@physician.availabilities.sample(5).class
=> Array
```

whereas I want to retrain an ActiveRecord object (so I can `.save` the random sample but not the others)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this in two queries.

```
ids = @physician.availabilities.sample(5).pluck(:id)
@physician.availabilities.where(id: ids)
```

This is also possible using Postgres with `RANDOM`

```
@physician.availabilities.order('RANDOM()').limit(5)
```

...or if you are into MySQL with `RAND`

```
@physician.availabilities.order('RAND()').limit(5)
```